# 98 Mustang Randomly loses power w/ gas smell

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, mustang, smell, intermittent-problems

So when I'm driving around, and specifically when it's humid as I've noticed, my car will randomly lose power and when at a constant speed, start lurching back and forth. Every time this happens, all I have to do is put my foot to the floor in 1st, 2nd, or 3rd and power will come back in a jolt and it'll ride smoothly at constant speeds until it decides to do it again. The idle RPM will also drop to around 500 rpms when this happens and you can smell gas/burning while stopped. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which engine is in your Mustang?

Comment: 3.8 1998 mustang

Comment: My thinking is you might have an issue with the throttle position sensor (TPS), but with it being intermittent would be hard to prove. You might be able to catch it when the issue is happening. The "typical" way to check it is to transition the throttle while from closed to FOT while watching the throttle %. It should be smooth all the way across. If there's any stops, where the % stays then jumps, this would indicate an issue with the TPS.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. I'm guessing I'd need an OBDII sensor again. I've also heard that it could be my MAF sensor since its intermediate. The gas smell makes me think it's a leak but a leak wouldn't cause intermediate problems, right? Do you think the TPS would cause the gas smell as well or am I looking at 2 problems instead of one?

Comment: It very well be you could be looking at two issues, but they are most likely related. Focus on one issue at a time, though, or it will drive you crazy.

Comment: Fantastic lol. I'm not doubting your opinion but if it isnt the TPS, what's the next 1-2 things you think it could be? I like having lists so I can just go through instead of stopping what I'm doing and waiting for more answers when one doesnt work

Comment: I really don't know ... was hoping someone would pop in here. The TPS is just somewhere I'd start. It might be the MAF, and would be something to check, but not really sure how you can check it on your Mustang. You might just try cleaning it with electronics spray cleaner.

Comment: Any codes in the fuel computer?

Comment: Yeah, plenty. P1443, P1131 and 1151, p1000, p1260, and another p1443. The P1260 could be something, but that's just for emissions so I havent thought much of it.

Comment: I mean the *1443